# Make .mpkg so it can be installed by script on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, installation, mpkg

I want to make a .mpkg that can be installed by a script on OSX. When starting the .mpkg always the GUI-dialog shows up. I tried to disable the GUI, but there seems to be no effective way to do so.

Does anyone got an hint for me how to do so?
Any answers are helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to modify the .mpkg or .pkg created by PackageMaker in such a way, so that they run without a user dialog. But you can run all .pkg/.mpkg in silentmode: http://blog.elitecoderz.net/run-installer-pkg-or-mpkg-without-user-dialog-silentmode-from-console-on-os-x/2010/07/ explains how to do so.